# JSF 2.0 Tags not appearing on Tomcat 6.0 Server

Tags: jsp, jsf, tomcat, xhtml, tomcat6

I have just deployed my first JSF site using eatj.com.

I have tested my application on netbeans using glassfish and the site with JSF tags runs fine on localhost.

I have uploaded the project file by ftp to the webapps director folder on the tomcat server.

The jsp-api.jar file is present in the /lib file on the Tomcat server.

When i restart the server and go to /webapps/myproject/web/index.xhtml the page loads but non of the jsf tags are visible.

I have tried to copy the jar libraries to /webapps/myproject/web/WEB-INF/lib/ however there is  no change.

Perhaps it is something to do with the fact my home page is .xhtml not .jsf? But I would have thought if it worked on my localhost then it work work on this server?

I am sure that the server supports JSF as there are examples of JSF pages running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

edit:

Below is my current web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Edit:

Below is a paste from my catalina.out file for server startup:

```
INFO: Server startup in 1594 ms
May 7, 2012 1:09:50 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-6713
May 7, 2012 1:09:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
May 7, 2012 1:09:51 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-6713
May 7, 2012 1:09:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: 
May 7, 2012 1:09:57 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-6713
May 7, 2012 1:09:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1017 ms
May 7, 2012 1:09:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 7, 2012 1:09:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.14
May 7, 2012 1:09:59 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-6713
May 7, 2012 1:09:59 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:4713
May 7, 2012 1:09:59 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/62  config=null
May 7, 2012 1:09:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1580 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSF tags will only be processed if the request URL matches the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` in `web.xml`. You seem to have mapped it on `*.jsf`, but the `<welcome-file>` of `index.xhtml` does not match that. You have 2 options:

- Map the `FacesServlet` on an `<url-pattern>` of `*.xhtml` instead of `*.jsf`. This way you never need to fiddle with virtual URLs.
- Change `<welcome-file>` to `index.jsf` and create an empty `index.jsf` file next to `index.xhtml` in the root folder to fool the server that it really exists, to prevent a 404 error.

By the way, the confirmation that you've a `jsp-api.jar` file in Tomcat's `/lib` is irrelevant to this problem. First, that's standard part of Tomcat and second, that's not used at all when you're using Facelets.

Last but not least, make sure that you ship a concrete JSF implementation along with your webapp in its `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. Tomcat does as being a simple JSP/Servlet container namely not ship with JSF bundled, while Glassfish as being a full fledged Java EE application server does. If you don't have any one, [download](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) and drop the `javax.faces.jar` file in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp before deploying to Tomcat. Also make sure that your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 2.5, because Tomcat 6 is a rather old version which doesn't support Servlet 3.0 like as Glassfish 3.

Comment: And if you need Servlet 3.0 you can use Tomcat 7.

Comment: @Mark: Indeed, but eat4j.com only offers Tomcat 6 hosting. I'd personally rather step over to openshift.com. Free cloud hosting on JBoss AS 7.

Comment: Fair enough. The whole point of the J2EE specs is that you can move your app from one spec complaint  container to another - picking the one that works best for you.

Comment: Hi thank you for the fast and helpful reply. I have changed the jar in the /WEB-INF/lib folder to the javax.faces.jar file so that is now the only jar present. Previously my <url-pattern> was /faces/* however I have changed it to *.xhtml and I am still having the same problem. Please see edit for my web.xml file

Comment: Your `<welcome-file>` is wrong, but that should have resulted in a different problem and only when you try to open a folder by URL. Please check the server startup logs to see if JSF has properly initialized.

Comment: Should the <welcome-file> just be /index.xhtml? Please see edit for paste from my catalina.out

Comment: The `<welcome-file>` should represent the sole filename of a file in the current folder which is to be served whenever the folder is been requested by URL. So, you should specify just `index.xhtml`. Your log is missing the JSF initialization log. It seems that it isn't properly deployed or that eat4j somehow didn't load it.

Comment: Any further suggestions? Thanks a lot for your help I have signed up for the openshift.com so will perhaps try there

Comment: As said, it seems that it isn't deployed, or that eat4j didn't load it. Verify if the JAR is really in `/WEB-INF/lib` of built WAR file. Verify if the JAR is really expanded on eat4j's side. OpenShift runs JBoss AS 7 which has JSF already bundled (like Glassfish), so you don't need to supply JSF libs yourself. Tomcat is just a simple barebones JSP/Servlet container, not a Java EE app server.